# Missing feature title while exporting cucumber feature to .feature file in Xray?

Tags: cucumber, jira-xray

While exporting the cucumber file (feature) from Xray Test Execution I recently notice that the feature name is missing (it should be imported from test/task name?)

```
> @XYZ-1234 Feature:
> 
>   #description    @XYZ-1234 @XYZ-1234 @XYZ-1234 @Tag_name
>   Scenario: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
>       Given Consectetur adipiscing elit
>       Then  Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua
```

**Is there any possibility to add a feature name in Xray?**

When you generate a JSON report via **wdio-cucumberjs-json-reporter** package then JSON doesn't have a name, just ".json", when I add a feature name like shown below it works fine but the features will be exported via CI/CD so I need to point out the right JSON with the correct name.

```
> @XYZ-1234 Feature: Added title manually
> 
>   #description    @XYZ-1234 @XYZ-1234 @XYZ-1234 @Tag_name
>   Scenario: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
>       Given Consectetur adipiscing elit
>       Then  Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua
```

Is there any solution to resolve that case?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to populate the "Feature: " field,  you need to have Tests in Xray linked to "requirements" (i.e issues that can be covered with Tests). Those "requirement" issues need to have one of the issue types configured to be handled as "requirements as detailed in the [documentation](https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAY/Quick+Setup#QuickSetup-ConfigureRequirementsandDefects)

The rules for generating the .feature files are detailed [here](https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAY/Export+Cucumber+Features)

Btw, in the recent Xray v4.2.3, Xray will autofill the Feature: section with a default name if your Test scenarios are not linked to a "requirement"; more info [here](https://jira.xpand-it.com/browse/XRAY-5611?src=confmacro).

Comment: Sergio, thank you very much, now it makes sense. We have a separate X-ray test repository and we didn't have any requirements issue-types set up yet.