# Copying Label Tags from Xray Requirement Issue type to Cucumber Feature file

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, jira-plugin, jira-xray

Should Label field tags in Jira Requirement Issue type be copied to Cucumber Feature section? We use Feature tags heavily to login and logout our test application in almost all Features.

[image]

using Jira DC v8.9.0 with Xray v6.1.3

Answer (score 0):

To be clear, Xray doesn't import the "Feature" section. It just imports Background and Sceneario/Scenario Outline, as Precondition and Test issues respectively.
Whenever you import .feature files, only Test and Preconditions may be created. Test issues will contain labels based on the existing tags on the corresponding Scenario/Scenario Outline.
Therefore, I'm not sure how you got the labels on the  requirement issue, which I think is the "Enhancement & Roadmap" issue type in your case.
Whenever you export/Generate .feature files from Xray, then [these rules](https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAY/Export+Cucumber+Features) apply as I've mentioned on a previous question; labels from the requirement issue are not mapped to tags on the Feature section of the generate .feature file.
You may/should reach out to [Xray support team](https://jira.getxray.app/servicedesk/customer/portal/2/user/login?destination=portal%2F2) and ask for this improvement, so that the Xray product team can analyze it in detail.

Comment: You are right @Sergio, my bad I got it confused when I said "Feature section was copied to Jira label field". I have removed that part. Now I remember I had added those label values in requirement issue manually for some other reason but coming back to my question, at our workplace as we use feature tags in cucumber almost all the time do you think adding "Requirement Issue Label" parameter be doable? I will reaching out to Xray support on this but just wanted your thoughts. 
`[@{ Requirement Issue Label 1 } ... @{ Requirement Issue Label N}] 
Feature: [{ Requirement Issue Summary }] 
...`

Comment: Another quick question on Feature definition, I have this Requirement Issue Type 'Enhancement & Roadmap' linked to all Tests but I still see 'Default' at Feature when exported. I checked your reply [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65199551/4777737) and all looks good in my case.

Comment: I've updated slightly the answer. On your last question, I think it's a different one and should be treated as such for better visibility here on this community. Nevertheless, please check the issue links you have on your requirement issue and also whether that issue type is configured to be handled as a requirement or not

Comment: Yeah I have all Tests linked to my requirement issue and scenarios are getting created in the .feature file on export and I also have 'Enhancement & Roadmap' under Requirement Issue Type in Issue Type Mapping.

Comment: I got help from Xray support for my comment on [seeing 'Default' in Feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72051589/copying-label-tags-from-xray-requirement-issue-type-to-cucumber-feature-file#comment127329441_72052079) my question there was on Requirement Issue key not getting mapped but the solution I got also fixed Feature title and description. Anyways, I had to check 'Generate Features By Requirement' in Xray Setting to make it work. More details [here](https://jira.getxray.app/servicedesk/customer/portal/2/SUPPORT-50584) from Xray Support.

Comment: For my [first comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72051589/copying-label-tags-from-xray-requirement-issue-type-to-cucumber-feature-file#comment127328735_72052079) there is an suggestion opened in Xray to add Requirement Issue labels on export. https://jira.getxray.app/browse/XRAY-6461